# BadgeView: ParentView is needed

Tags: android

I have created an custom adapter for a listview, and I want to show a badge for a row. I didn't get any errors as such, but the badge didn't appear either. When I looked at the logcat, there was a message "BadgeView: ParentView is needed". But I already have provided one.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.jauker.widget.BadgeView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AdminViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> resnum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static Context context;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public AdminViewAdapter(Context mainActivity, List<String> ADMINFUNCTIONS, List<Integer> NUMBERS) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=ADMINFUNCTIONS;
    resnum = NUMBERS;
    context=mainActivity;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public static class Holder
{
    TextView os_text;
    BadgeView badgeView;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;
    Holder holder =new Holder();
    if(v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_functions, null);
        holder.os_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.receptionistfunctions);
        if (result.toArray()[position].toString().contains("ACCOUNT")) {
            holder.os_text.setTextAlignment(v.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
            holder.os_text.setText(result.toArray()[position].toString());
            holder.badgeView = new BadgeView(context);
            holder.badgeView.setTargetView(holder.os_text);
            holder.badgeView.setBadgeGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            holder.badgeView.setBadgeMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
            holder.badgeView.setBadgeCount(22);
        }
        else if (result.toArray()[position].toString().contains("LEAVE")) {
           /* holder.os_text.setTextAlignment(v.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
            holder.os_text.setText(result.toArray()[position].toString());
            BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(context);
            badge.setTag(target);
            badge.setText(resnum.toArray()[1].toString());
            badge.show();*/
        }
        else {
            holder.os_text.setText(result.toArray()[position].toString());
        }
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (AdminViewAdapter.Holder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    return v;
}}
```

There are no other errors. I have tried using another View variable for the Badge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not add your `BadgeView` to any view group so your `BadgeView` does not have a parent. That is why you see that message. Views should have a parent!

I Think you can fix this by adding `BadgeView` to your adapter layout programmatically by using [ViewGroup#addView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)) method, like this `((ViewGroup) v).addView(holder.badgeView)`. Or even better, modify your adapter layout to have a `BadgeView` inside of it.

**EDIT :**

You can modify your `getView()` method like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    Holder holder =new Holder();
    if(v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_functions, null);
        // ...
        holder.badgeView = new BadgeView(context);
        holder.badgeView.setTargetView(holder.os_text);
        holder.badgeView.setBadgeGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        holder.badgeView.setBadgeMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
        holder.badgeView.setBadgeCount(22);
        // Add this line
        ((ViewGroup) v).addView(holder.badgeView);
    }
    // ...
}}
```

Comment: I am getting the UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView when I try to do parent.addView(holder.badgeView). How exactly do I modify the adapter layout to have a BadgeView inside of it. Sorry.

Comment: @RuturajGole sorry about late reply. I have edited my answer. Please check if it now solves your problem or not.

Comment: It's okay. I appreciate you answering me. But there are two problems, (1) v is a View, and not a ViewGroup. So I cannot do v.addView(). (2) parent is a ViewGroup, but when I try to do parent.addView(holder.badgeView), I get the UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView error.

Comment: oh! sorry my bad. I forgot to cast `v` to `ViewGroup`. Fixed my answer. :)

Comment: By the way, Why don't you add `BadgeView` to `list_functions` layout?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It got solved when I enclosed the textview inside a linear layout.